# Calling jQuery functions in HTML links?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make these jQuery commands execute later through links in html:

```
                    $('#mov').click(function() {
                            $('#twastream').hide();
                            $('#ownstream').hide();                                     
                            $('#movstream').fadeIn();
                    }
```

This is supposed to hide two elements and show one after a link with the id "mov" is clicked, but nothing is happening. This is the link:

```
                    <a href="test/#" onclick="mov()">Click here!</a>
```

This is the element; all three are similarly formatted.

```
                   <div class="movstream" id="movstream">
```

How am I supposed to change how these are formatted in order to make the initial code function correctly?

Comment: `$("#mov")` is a type of [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) not a function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have an id on your anchor tag for your jquery selector `$('#mov')` to work:

```
<a href="test/#" id="mov">Click here!</a>
```

Using `onclick="mov()"` on your anchor means to execute a function named `mov`, which is undefined

You also need to wrap your `.click` event in `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mov').click(function() {
        $('#twastream').hide();
        $('#ownstream').hide();                                     
        $('#movstream').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Otherwise the element may not exist when the script runs

Comment: I'd also add a `return false;` so that the anchor's default behavior is not triggered.

Comment: Alright, I've added the correct anchor to the link but it's still not doing anything. Is there a way for one of these to be triggered as the page loads, as opposed to only after pressing a button? Currently, all three elements are shown in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The strength of jQuery is in its ability to make tasks like this mundane.

First, give your link either a **class** or an **id** (a class would work if this can happen on any given number of links) and then bind your event in the background, like this:

HTML

```
<a href="/#" class="test" /> 
<!--OR-->
<a href="/#" id="test" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(".test").click(function(){ //Or $("#test")
     $('#twastream').hide();
     $('#ownstream').hide();                                     
     $('#movstream').fadeIn();
});
```

It might be helpful to go and review the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), too.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is happening because you don't have an ID specified on the anchor. The jQuery is looking for a click on an element with the id of "mov" but there isn't an element with that id.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for your event inside a ready handler:

```
$(function() {
   $('#mov').click(function() {
      $('#twastream').hide();
      $('#ownstream').hide();                                     
      $('#movstream').fadeIn();
   });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

And you you need to be sure that the `.click` function specifies the selector correctly. Notice that `$('#mov')` is the selector for an item with the `id` of `mov`. This works for classes as well.

```
<a id="mov">Click here!</a>     
<div class="twastream" id="twastream">Twas</div>
<div class="ownstream" id="ownstream">Own</div>
<div class="movstream" id="movstream">Mov</div>
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/